# Buttons created programmatically doesn't receive touch up inside events... UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicontrolevents

I'm creating Collection View Cells programmatically using Facade framework to position it right. Unfortunately buttons inside cells doesn't react to touches. 
Collection View is created using storyboard.
CollectionViewCell appearance loading:

```
_likesButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_likesButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:0.10]];
_likesButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 8, 5, 8);
_likesButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
_likesButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
[_likesButton setAttributedTitle:[self attributedSpacedStringFromString:@"+10039" withColor:[UIColor flatWhiteColor] withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Bold" size:12]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_likesButton.layer.cornerRadius = 12;
[_likesButton sizeToFit];
_likesButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

In Collection View:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.likesButton.tag = indexPath.row;
[[cell likesButton] addTarget:self action:@selector(showAlert:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Best regards,

Adrian.

Comment: are you sure buttons are added in cell? try to give background color to button and see...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just figured it out...
I had image as background (UIButton was subview) and UIImageView has *userInteractionEnabled* disabled as default. Setting this property to YES, fixed issue.